# Regression model has very high const VIF value where as the other features have value between less than 4. Should I drop const?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, statsmodels, variance-inflation-factor, feature-scaling

I am a beginner in modelling. I have created a **linear regression** model using **statsmodel** and I see the **const** has VIF value around 124 where as the other features have value around 4. I already referred to a post and that says this is scaling issue. But I have used **MinMaxScaler** and all the features are between 0-1. Is this because the const is highly correlated with my features and I should drop it? If not, please help me understand what else might be the reason. Here is the kaggle norebook link. Open for suggestions on my work.

https://www.kaggle.com/sownikturaga96/housing-prices-dataset-modelling

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is “const”, the intercept/constant? I do not see how to calculate a variance inflation factor for the intercept.

Comment: Hi, indeed, it's because of your scaling; use a StandardScaler and you'll get a VIF of zero for the intercept.

Comment: @JohnMadden [I have posted a question based on your comment.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/600822/247274)

Comment: Hello Dave, Thanks for the quick response. I will use StandardScaler and see the VIF for intercept. My understanding from your post is intercept should not show any correlation with other features because it's a constant (variance is 0).

Comment: @SownikTuraga As my linked question indicates, VIF for the intercept does not make much sense to me. // I’ve added the [tag:statsmodels] tag. One of the developers is on across Validated and seems to watch the tag. He has helped me a number of times and I hope can do the same here for you.