# Intercept variance inflation factor?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, r-squared, variance-inflation-factor

In the comments to the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/600806/247274), John Madden remarks about the variance inflation factor (VIF) of the intercept of a linear model. Does such a notion exist?

My argument against such a notion is as follows:

1. We calculate VIF by using the other features in a regression to predict the feature for which we want to calculate the VIF. We get the VIF from the $R^2$ of this regression: $VIF=\frac{1}{1-R^2}$. (Assume estimation via ordinary least squares.)
2. But the variable being predicted in that regression is a constant, so that $R^2$ either equals zero (can’t do better than an intercept-only model) or doesn’t even make sense of we calculate based on squared correlation (constant has no variance, so correlation is a bit dubious).

What is the resolution?

Comment: thanks for this question. I think what's required to reconcile your question with my comment is the fact that your "inner regression" (to estimate the constant given the other variables) doesn't contain an intercept, so the interpretation of $R^2$ as improvement over the intercept-only model doesn't hold, and hence neither does the subsequent assertion"so that R2 either equals zero (can’t do better than an intercept-only model) or doesn’t even make sense of we calculate based on squared correlation (constant has no variance, so correlation is a bit dubious)"; this $R^2$ is instead given...

Comment: ... as the squared norm of the projection of the constant vector $\mathbf{1}$ onto the range of $\mathbf{X}_{\neq1}$ (the matrix of nonconstant predictors). [Which is 0 if that matrix is centered as is the context for my comment cited by your question]

Comment: @JohnMadden It would be great to see that expanded into an answer!